# unity3d serial port delay Update problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, serial-port, delay

i need to send something over a serial and continue to send those values for about 10 seconds, after the 10 seconds send and different value and so on and so on.

below is my code so far it works just need help with the delay

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;


public class Mindwave : MonoBehaviour
{
    TGCConnectionController controller;


    private SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM9", 9600);
    string strIn;


    public Texture2D[] signalIcons;

    private int indexSignalIcons = 1;

    private int poorSignal1;
    private int attention1;
    private int meditation1;

    private float delta;




        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
    {
        controller = GameObject.Find("NeuroSkyTGCController").GetComponent<TGCConnectionController>();

        controller.UpdatePoorSignalEvent += OnUpdatePoorSignal;
        controller.UpdateAttentionEvent += OnUpdateAttention;
        controller.UpdateMeditationEvent += OnUpdateMeditation;

        controller.UpdateDeltaEvent += OnUpdateDelta;

        sp.Open();
        sp.ReadTimeout = 50;


    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        print ("Attention1:" + attention1);

        if (sp.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                //Read incoming data
                //strIn = sp.ReadLine();
                //print(strIn);
                if (attention1 < 50)
                {
                    sp.Write("4");
                }else if (attention1 > 60)
                {
                    // sp.Write("3");

                    Invoke("DoSomething", 10);//this will happen after 2 seconds
                    sp.Write("1");
                    Invoke("DoSomething", 10);//this will happen after 2 seconds
                    yield WaitForSeconds(0.3);
                }


            }

            catch (System.Exception)
            {


            }


        }



    }


    void OnUpdatePoorSignal(int value){
        poorSignal1 = value;
        if(value < 25){
            indexSignalIcons = 0;
        }else if(value >= 25 && value < 51){
            indexSignalIcons = 4;
        }else if(value >= 51 && value < 78){
            indexSignalIcons = 3;
        }else if(value >= 78 && value < 107){
            indexSignalIcons = 2;
        }else if(value >= 107){
            indexSignalIcons = 1;
        }
    }
    void OnUpdateAttention(int value){
        attention1 = value;
    }
    void OnUpdateMeditation(int value){
        meditation1 = value;
    }
    void OnUpdateDelta(float value){
        delta = value;
    }


    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();


        if (GUILayout.Button("Connect"))
        {
            controller.Connect();
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("DisConnect"))
        {
            controller.Disconnect();
            indexSignalIcons = 1;
        }

        GUILayout.Space(Screen.width-250);
        //GUILayout.Label(signalIcons[indexSignalIcons]);

        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();


        GUILayout.Label("PoorSignal1:" + poorSignal1);
        GUILayout.Label("Attention1:" + attention1);
        GUILayout.Label("Meditation1:" + meditation1);
        GUILayout.Label("Delta:" + delta);


    }

    public void StartClicked()
    {
        sp.Write("5");
    }
}
```

the above code is my code so far and below is the part i want to add the delay to

```
if (attention1 < 50)
            {
                sp.Write("4");
            }else if (attention1 > 60)
            {
                // sp.Write("3");

                Invoke("DoSomething", 10);//this will happen after 2 seconds
                sp.Write("1");
                Invoke("DoSomething", 10);//this will happen after 2 seconds
                yield WaitForSeconds(0.3);
            }
```

as you can see i want to send 3 for 10 seconds then send 1 for 10 seconds and so on

if anyone could help that would be great thank you

Comment: You send 3 for 10 seconds, 1 for 10 seconds the what do you send next? How do you determine what to send next?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `IEnumerator ` with a `yield return wait for seconds` instead of using a [instable](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate) version of `update` ?